# Java does not produce proper AltGr key event

Tags: java, events, keyboard

I'm pressing the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key in my Java application, but instead of receiving a KeyEvent with key code VK_ALT_GRAPH I get two events. The first with key code VK_CONTROL and the second with VK_ALT.

Is this the correct behaviour?

Using Java 7 on Windows 7. Can be reproduced with the demo app found on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

When I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> it reports:

```
KEY PRESSED:
  key code = 17 (Ctrl)
  extended modifiers = 128 (Ctrl)
  action key? NO
  key location: left
KEY PRESSED:
  key code = 18 (Alt)
  extended modifiers = 640 (Ctrl+Alt)
  action key? NO
  key location: right
KEY RELEASED:
  key code = 17 (Ctrl)
  extended modifiers = 512 (Alt)
  action key? NO
  key location: left
KEY RELEASED:
  key code = 18 (Alt)
  extended modifiers = 0 (no extended modifiers)
  action key? NO
  key location: right
```

Comment: On Linux (Ubuntu) it only fires one event but with key code 0 and not VK_ALT_GRAPH (I guess you can check the state with isAltGraphDown). This behavior seems to be highly platform specific. Is this a bug?

Comment: This seems to be a general win32 issue with some keyboard layouts (german-swiss for instance). I wish to move that question to win32 input, not sure that would help finding solutions..

Answer (score 4):

in windows, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> are Synonyms. in some locales(keyboard layouts?, they are both treated as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, in others, they are both treated as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. However, I am not completely sure.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511502.aspx and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to find AltGr.

Comment: Yes, I heard the same. But this is just a convenience thing for people who don't have the AltGr key. I believe Windows distinguishes between Ctrl+Alt and AltGr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of getKeyCode and getKeyLocation. When you press "Alt" you get "18" and "2" respectively, but when you press "Alt Gr" you get two values for each one, "17,18" and "2,3". Here "2" and "3" represent keys side, and "18" is the alt key code, so you can do the following:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == 18 && e.getKeyLocation() == 3){
    System.out.println("Only triggers with Alt Gr");
}
```