# How do I disable AltGr-to-Alt-and-Ctrl key translations in PyCharm?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm, dvorak

I have a custom Swedish Dvorak keyboard layout which relies heavily on the AltGr modifier on Swedish keyboards. However, when I hit e.g. AltGr+u (which should generate a forward slash), PyCharm interprets it as Alt+Ctrl+u, which is apparently bound to something special.

Since I'd rather not play whack-a-mole with PyCharm...is there any way to solve this in any way other than removing all taken Alt+Ctrl key bindings manually?

Comment: This problem may come from [Java itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8795818/777285), on which is based Pycharm. I sympathize since I use the French Dvorak myself, I experience similar incoherences on mac, just had to make do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to give [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) a try.  The command sequence `<^>!` listens for the AltGr modifier key, like so:

```
<^>!u::Send {/}
```

This line should listen for the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> key sequence and send the forward slash as expected.  Because AutoHotKey listens to the keyboard and then intercepts keystrokes and sends characters separate from the underlying applications, it *should* be able to grab the keystroke you use and send the correct character to PyCharm, before PyCharm has a chance to interpret and alter the keystroke on its own.

This suggestion is based on similar situations I have dealt with.  I have neither PyCharm nor a Swedish keyboard (Dvorak or otherwise) with which to test this.

Comment: I don't think I'd like to go back to AHK, to be honest. I used it for my Dvorak before, but since it was kind of buggy every now and again, I made my own proper Windows keyboard layout, which is what I'm using now.

Comment: Heh, AHK is my go-to for too many things.  Still, you don't have to redo the whole keyboard with that, just make a brief script for the keys that are malfunctioning.  You could even put in a conditional so it only changes the keys in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a german keyboard layout.
I need to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> in order to print a '[', which I need for programming all the time. PyCharm interprets this as a shortcut for jumping in the code. This was really annoying.

For me it works fine, when I switch from 'Visual Studio' to 'Eclipse' keymap settings in PyCharm.